# Knockoutjs nested ViewModel / component binding with typescript doesn't work

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, web-component

I've been struggling to try to get a viewModel within a viewModel to work in knockout.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm using typescript and want a list of address controls, each with their own viewmodel.

The project worked perfectly well with just the one address control, but when adding the controls to a parent container viewmodel and using components the child viewmodel is always empty (i.e. {} as demonstrated by the alert statements below):

Here is my app.ts, complete code at https://github.com/richbeales/knockout-test

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/retyped-knockout-tsd-ambient/knockout.d.ts"/>

import * as ko from 'knockout';
import {AddressViewModel, Address} from './components/paf-widget';

ko.components.register('paf-address', {
    viewModel: AddressViewModel, // { require: 'components/paf-widget' },
    template: { require: 'text!components/paf-widget.html' }
});

class AddressesViewModel {
    addressList: KnockoutObservableArray<AddressViewModel>;

    constructor() {
        this.addressList = ko.observableArray<AddressViewModel>();
    }

    addAddress = function () {
        alert(ko.toJSON(this)); // returns {"addressList":[{}]}

        var childVm = new AddressViewModel();
        alert(ko.toJSON(childVm)); // returns {}
        childVm.chosenAddress(new Address());
        childVm.chosenAddress().Organisation = "Test";
        alert(ko.toJSON(childVm)); // returns {}

        var a = new Address();
        a.AddressLine1 = "The Street";
        alert(ko.toJSON(a)); // returns {"AddressLine1":"The Street"}

        this.addressList.push(childVm);
    }
}

var vm = new AddressesViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bootstrap with jQuery and KnockoutJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<header>

</header>

<h1>App</h1>

Choose an Address
 <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(addressList, null, 2)"></pre>

<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: addressList, as: 'addrVm'}" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="addressli">
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(addrVm, null, 2)"></pre>
        <div data-bind="component: {name: 'paf-address', with: addrVm }"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addAddress">Add an address</button>

<footer>

</footer>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js" data-main="js/app"></script>
<script src="require-config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this strange problem because you are loading knockout multiple times and inconsistently.

The first time directly in your `index.html` and then with require.js in your `app.js`. So your `AddressViewModel` uses a different `ko` instance than your `AddressesViewModel` and that is why you see these strange empty objects.

The easiest way to fix it is to remove the direct reference to KO in your index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

And properly include knockout in your `paf-widget.ts`, with:

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';
```

Note: after the change make sure that your browser cache is clear and picking up the new code properly.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple.  Many Thanks!